# Sending html mail from a php script

Tags: php, html, session, file-get-contents

I want to send an html email from my script. I get the email's html using `file_get_contents` - but I found out the `$_SESSION` isn't shared between the 2 pages (and `other_script.php` needs some data that is stored in the `$_SESSION` array).

this is the code in my send email function:

```
$url ="OTHER_SCRIPT.php";
$html = file_get_contents($url);
$from ;
$crlf = "\r\n";
$mime = @new Mail_mime($crlf); 
@$mime->setHTMLBody($html);  
//SEND MAIL...
```

Is there another way to get the output of a script to a variable that will share the session data? or a way to make the `$_SESSION` data available to my `other_script.php`?

Comment: Are you making a call to `session_start()` in both scripts?

Comment: yes, I am - I think that maybe because I am using file_get_contents somehow it isn't shared properly

Answer (score 3):

You are probably not writing `session_start()` in both pages.

All the `$_SESSIONS` are shared between your PHP pages if they have `session_start()` written.

Answer (score 1):

You have two methods for that :

1) You can use writing session_start() on the both pages

2) can using PHPSESSID as the [link discussed earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370951/what-is-phpsessid)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use PHPSESSID :

```
$url ="OTHER_SCRIPT.php?PHPSESSID=".session_id();
```

Here a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370951/what-is-phpsessid).