# PHPSESSID is blank when I echo this

Tags: php, session

`PHPSESSID` is blank when I

`echo $PHPSESSID`

But in `php.ini` file I have added

`session.name = PHPSESSID`

I am using `PHP 5.4.35` .What is the problem here?

Comment: Maybe, it's inside cookies: `print $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'];`

Comment: There is no variable with PHPSESSID name in php by default.

Comment: You might find your solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370951/what-is-phpsessid as @user4035 said, you'll find it in a cookie, which of course you'll have to set first.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`session_id`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php) function. This retrieves the value of the session id regardless of the name that was used to create the session (cookie or otherwise).

If you are interested in getting the name, you could use use `ini_get("session.name")`.

Answer (score 4):

You should use `$_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']`, for example:

```
session_start();
echo session_id();
print $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'];
```

will print you Session's ID twice, one by `echo session_id();` and second by `print $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'];`

Answer (score 2):

`$PHPSESSID` is not correct. `PHPSESSID` is an index of array `$_COOKIE[]`. Example:

```
echo $_COOKIE["PHPSESSID"];
```

This cookie starts when you start a session.