# How to pass PHP_session_id in curl request

Tags: php, curl

I am learning PHP and trying to automate a website login and then post some data to another page once logged in. I managed to login to the website and when I try to post data, I got a "Document moved".

Then I analysed the headers in firebug and realised that there was a PHP_session_id, so when I tried to manually pass this PHP_session_id it worked.

So my question is, how can I automatically get the sessionid when I login and then subsequently pass this on to my second request?

This is what my code looks like:

```
<?php
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://www.example.com/login-main.php");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
                "loginType=company&username=johndoe%40gmail.com&password=1234&company=test");

    ob_start();
    curl_exec ($ch);
    ob_end_clean();
    curl_close ($ch);
    unset($ch);

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(

    'Host:www.example.com',
    'Origin:http://www.example.com',
    'Cookie:PHPSESSID=na6ivnsdfab206ktb453o2au07',
    'Referer:http://www.example.com/bookings/'

        ));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://www.example.com/bookings.php");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
                "start_date=&end_date=&type=instructor&b_type=&id=41");
    $buf2 = curl_exec ($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
    echo "<PRE>".htmlentities($buf2);
?>
```

Comment: Searching for PHPSESSID gives http://stackoverflow.com/q/1370951/1741542. Maybe this helps.

Comment: This might help, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13020404/keeping-session-alive-with-curl-and-php

Comment: To follow "Document moved", you must add [`CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION.html), IIRC. See also https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html for many more options.

Comment: @OlafDietsche Thanks, I checked that out and I have added that to my code but now am getting a 404 error.

Comment: Have you removed the hardwired "Cookie: …"?

Comment: Yes, I have. I am using a cookie file as suggested by @Garden_Apple

Comment: Then maybe it's a real 404, or the page is missing some other parameter.

Comment: Well, when i hardcode the `'Cookie:PHPSESSID=na6ivnsdfab206ktb453o2au07',` it works, so im confused.

Comment: You do a `curl_close()` after the first request and then create a new one. Do you fully initialize the second request, including cookie jar, etc.? Maybe it works, when you continue using the first curl handle.

Comment: Oh I see. What I tried now is to use `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $full_path_to_cookie_file);` in the first request and then call that cookie `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $full_path_to_cookie_file); ` in the second request. Is that correct?

Comment: I don't know, I haven't tried this myself. From the docs, I would guess, you need both. Just try and you will see. If some combination doesn't work, try another.

Comment: If everything else fails, read the manual :-)

Comment: Great, i'll try different things and see what finally works. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Add to your code in all curl requests

```
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $full_path_to_cookie_file);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $full_path_to_cookie_file);
```

For example

```
$full_path_to_cookie_file= __DIR__.'/cookie.txt';
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but it still returns a "document moved". Do I have to extract just the phpsessid from the cookie and pass this in the header?

Comment: File cookie.txt will contain all cookies of page. Cookie.txt will contain phpsessid too.

Comment: Ah I see. Any idea why it doesn't work? I can't figure out what I am missing because I understood the idea of getting and sending the cookie file based on your answer.